# Passing callback function to d3.xml?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scope, callback

Say I use `d3.xml()` within a function to load an SVG asset into the browser. If I would like to call a callback function ("`cb`") once the asset is loaded into memory, how would I do this?

As example code, I tried the following:

```
var svg_xml = null;
var load_svg = function(svg_path, cb) {
    d3.xml(svg_path, "image/svg+xml", function(error, xml) {
        if (error) throw error;
        svg_xml = xml;
        if (cb) cb;
    });
};
```

Then to test a callback elsewhere in the script:

```
load_svg("/foo/bar/baz.svg", function() {
    console.log("baz.svg loaded!");
});
```

The SVG is ultimately loaded into memory. However, the callback is not called — no log message results.

Is there a problem with scope for `cb` inside `load_svg`, such that `d3.xml()` does not know what `cb` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to call the callback `cb()`

```
var svg_xml = null;
var load_svg = function(svg_path, cb) {
    d3.xml(svg_path, "image/svg+xml", function(error, xml) {
       if (error) throw error;
       svg_xml = xml;
       if (cb) cb();
   });
};
```